# Print last occurrence (printing mistake)

Tags: java

```
public class TestForMatch2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] numbers1 = {0,2,4,6,7,11,0};
        int[] numbers2 = {-7,5,9,10,5,0};
        System.out.println(findTarget(numbers1,5));
        System.out.println(findTarget(numbers1,0));
        System.out.println(findTarget(numbers2,5));
        System.out.println(findTarget(numbers1,-1));
    }
    public static int findTarget(int[] arr, int target)
    {
        if (arr == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        int y = 0;
        int g = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i <= arr.length-1; i++) {
            if (target == arr[i]) {
                y = i;
                //return y;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(y);
        return -1;
    }
}

Output:
0
-1
6
-1
4
-1
0
-1
```

As you can see, there is a -1 that is being printed. If I remove the return -1, it gives me an error. How to remove the -1 without the error?

This is what is to be done.

Write a Java method to test if an array of integers contains a specific value.
If the value is in the array, returns the index of the element. If the value is more than once the method will return the index of the last occurrence of the value. 
If the value is not in the array, returns -1.

Copy and paste the following code. Then complete the method.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] numbers1 = {0,2,4,6,7,11,0};
        int[] numbers2 = {-7,5,9,10,5,0};
        System.out.println(findTarget(numbers1,5));
        System.out.println(findTarget(numbers1,0));
        System.out.println(findTarget(numbers2,5));
        System.out.println(findTarget(numbers1,-1));
    }
    public static int findTarget(int[] arr, int target)
    {
        //Type your code here
    }
}
```

This is the desired result. Ignore the numbers on the left. I put it there to emphasise on the space on number 5. Thank you for your time.

```
  1  -1
  2  6
  3  4
  4  -1
  5
```

Comment: "How to remove the -1 without the error?" -try `return y` and initialize `y` to -1.

Comment: "How to remove the -1 without the error?" - Restore `return y;` and remove `System.out.println(y);`

Comment: @BackSlash But by doing so, it prints the first occurrence not the last one.

Comment: @CateDoge Reverse the loop then, start from `array.length - 1` and decrease until you reach `0`.

Comment: Yes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] numbers1 = {0,2,4,6,7,11,0};
        int[] numbers2 = {-7,5,9,10,5,0};
        System.out.println(findTarget(numbers1,5));
        System.out.println(findTarget(numbers1,0));
        System.out.println(findTarget(numbers2,5));
        System.out.println(findTarget(numbers1,-1));
    }
    public static int findTarget(int[] arr, int target)
    {
        if (arr == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        int targetIndex = -1;
        for(int i = 0; i <= arr.length-1; i++) {
            if (target == arr[i]) {
                targetIndex = i;
            }
        }
        return targetIndex;
    }
```

Create a variable targetIndex which will keep the index of the target element, initially it is -1, if we find target element at index i, then our targetIndex becomes i, then we return it.

Comment: This worked. I just replaced the System.out with return. I also don't need the return -1 without the program failing. I don't know why. Maybe when I'm better I will understand. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. You don't need it because we are returning the variable `targetIndex`, which changes only if we find the target in the loop. If don't find the target in the loop, the if statement will not succeed and `targetIndex` will not change i.e. it will stay as -1, and that's what we are returning.

Comment: Yes, thank your explaining that. I understand a bit better  now.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `y = -1` and return `y`, you're returning `-1` no matter what you feed into the function.

Comment: Yes. That is what I'm trying to do. In my understanding, how little it may be, in order for the program to work, I need the last line return -1;  , without it, it would cause an error.   

How would I go about returning the printed without -1.  I tried initializing y to -1. It just gave me -1 0 1 and -1. Not the result asked in the instructions.

Comment: hi, have you returned y? , because you're returning -1?, you see if you don't return y , then you are always returning -1 constant.

Comment: Oh yes. I've found it. In the code above. I didn't understand how you explained it so I still returned -1 but the program is good now.

Comment: Oh sure. Thank you for your time and consideration. may you have good health!

Answer (score 0):

You did `System.out` twice per iteration. Do you know why?

You always print what y is - first `System.out()`:

```
System.out.println(y);
```

Then you *always* return -1:

```
return -1;
```

What gets printed too - second `System.out()`:

```
System.out.println(findTarget(numbers1,5));
```

You said: "If I remove the return -1, it gives me an error.".

--> You have to return an integer, since your method says "public static **int** findTarget(int[] arr, int target)". So it compiles if you `return -1`, since `-1` is an integer, but also if you return `y`, because you also assigned an integer to `y`.

So change the `findTarget()` to the following:

```
public static int findTarget(int[] arr, int target)
{
    if (arr == null) {
        return -1;
    }

    int y = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i <= arr.length-1; i++) {
        if (target == arr[i]) {
            y = i;
        }
    }
    return y;
}
```

Comment: Edited it, sorry.

Comment: Maybe but you didn't compile it.

Comment: It still won't compile.

Comment: Sorry, this does not work or I made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: @CateDoge try again now.

Comment: Yes. From the code above which is the same to yours. It works now. Thank you sir!

Comment: @CateDoge Did you also unterstand why it works and why you printed it twice before or can I help you with any clarification?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            int[] numbers1 = {0,2,4,6,7,11,0};
            int[] numbers2 = {-7,5,9,10,5,0};
            System.out.println(findTarget(numbers1,5));
            System.out.println(findTarget(numbers1,0));
            System.out.println(findTarget(numbers2,5));
            System.out.println(findTarget(numbers1,-1));
        }
        public static int findTarget(int[] arr, int target)
        {
            int index = -1;
            if(null != arr) {
                for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
                    if(arr[i] == target) {
                        index = i;
                    }
                }
            }
            return index;
        }
```